# No network-manager in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 15.04

I have a fresh Kubuntu 15.04 install.

When I go to the icon, right click, Networks Settings, I end up in this window: 
[image]

**Update:**  Same thing happens for Updates settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the network manager, click on the network icon. A popup will appear with the current network settings. You can then click on the settings icon on the right side of the popup (3/4 of the way to the top).

Comment: Thanks! Still I don't know why it doesn't work the other way. Or why the updates settings don't work.... I may be switching back to unity or maybe xfce

Comment: The settings window you opened is most likely for the icon settings itself. For example, if I set a keyboard shortcut there and then do that shortcut, then the popup will open.

Comment: It's actually quite possible.